# Get a cURL command from the PHP's object

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

Is it possible to get the cURL command from the PHP's object? I mean, make this:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://'.$host . $url);
//...
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Look like this:

```
curl -X POST -d http://www.google.com/
```

Is it possible? Is there a trick or a native method?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php

Comment: i've seen this. but any of those options will give me the curl command?

Comment: no. there's no php-in-curl-to-php-on-cli translator. php is **NOT** doing `shell_exec('curl....')`, period. it talks to the back-end curl library directly.

Comment: Hey @Victor. The command you've mentioned (`curl -X POST -d http://www.google.com/`) is invalid. Anyway, what you want to achieve is to execute a cURL request like you do from the command line, not get a string with the command, right?

Comment: @GustavoStraube I wanted to create a cURL object and get the command line from it. I know it's not valid, was just an example

Comment: @VictorFerreira, have you seen my answer below? Did that help you?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to get the command line equivalent (options) to execute the tool `curl` from the PHP library `cURL`.

Both tool and PHP library use `libcurl` to perform client-side URL transfers, which is a C library. But that's all. Very likely you have a PHP equivalent for most of `curl` options available in `cURL`, however, it's not a rule.

I don't think you simply would like to do requests from your application using `curl`, if you want so, you'd be using PHP library's. That said, there is no easy way to get what you want. Probably you'll need to build the command as a string. Something like this:

```php
function getCurlCommand($url, $method = 'GET', array $params = null /* , ... */ )
{
    $cmd = 'curl';
    $params = [];
    if ($method !== 'GET') {
        $params[] = '-X ' . $method;
    }
    if ($data !== null) {
        $params[] = '-d ' . http_build_query($data); 
    }

    // ...

    return $cmd . ' ' . implode(' ', $params) . ' ' . $url;
}
```